# Listview to pdf in android

Tags: android, listview, pdf, itext

I have a custom listview and I want to make pdf from the whole listview. I refered many posts and implemented below code which converts my *listview to pdf*. But problem is its not containing the whole listview item. Only first few items are available in the pdf.

My function to convert *listview to pdf* is

```
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
            if (!Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {

            }
            File pdfDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                    Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS), "MyProject");
            if (!pdfDir.exists()){
                pdfDir.mkdir();
            }
            Bitmap screen =  getWholeListViewItemsToBitmap();
            File pdfFile = new File(pdfDir, "myPdfFile_new.pdf");

            try {
                Document document = new Document();
                PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(pdfFile));
                document.open();
                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                screen.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
                addImage(document,byteArray);
                document.close();
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

addImage method

```
private static void addImage(Document document,byte[] byteArray)
{
    Image image = null;
    try
    {
        image = Image.getInstance(byteArray);
    }
    catch (BadElementException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try
    {
        document.add(image);
    } catch (DocumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

method to get list items

```
public Bitmap getWholeListViewItemsToBitmap() {

    ListView listview    = StockReportActivity.category_list;
    ListAdapter adapter  = listview.getAdapter();
    int itemscount       = adapter.getCount();
    int allitemsheight   = 0;
    List<Bitmap> bmps    = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();

    for (int i = 0; i < itemscount; i++) {

        View childView      = adapter.getView(i, null, listview);
        childView.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listview.getWidth(), View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
                View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));

        childView.layout(0, 0, childView.getMeasuredWidth(), childView.getMeasuredHeight());
        childView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        childView.buildDrawingCache();
        bmps.add(childView.getDrawingCache());
        allitemsheight+=childView.getMeasuredHeight();
    }
    Bitmap bigbitmap    = Bitmap.createBitmap(listview.getMeasuredWidth(), allitemsheight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas bigcanvas    = new Canvas(bigbitmap);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    int iHeight = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < bmps.size(); i++) {
        Bitmap bmp = bmps.get(i);
        bigcanvas.drawBitmap(bmp, 0, iHeight, paint);
        iHeight+=bmp.getHeight();
        bmp.recycle();
        bmp=null;
    }
     return bigbitmap;
    }
```

My listview contains large number of items in it, so how can i convert the whole listview to pdf. All your suggestions are appreciated

Comment: Please show your getWholeListViewItemsToBitmap(). Your issue is certainly there.

Comment: edited with getWholeListViewItemsToBitmap().

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the number of items displayed on screen in `recyclerView`, so create bitmap for first set of views, after that you can dynamically scroll to item below the last item displayed (i.e noOfItemDisplayed+1), again get bitmap, likewise all get all bitmaps into `ArrayList<Bitmap>` from which you can create pdf file, refer to code below to create pdf from arraylist of bitmaps:

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
private void createPdf() throws IOException {

    PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();
    PdfDocument.Page page = null;
    // crate a page description
    for (int i = 0; i < bitmaps.size(); i++) {
        Bitmap bitmap = bitmaps.get(i);
        PdfDocument.PageInfo pageInfo = new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(1400, 1979, i).create();

        // start a page
        page = document.startPage(pageInfo);
        if (page == null) {
            return;
        }
        Canvas canvas = page.getCanvas();
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);
        document.finishPage(page);
    }

    // finish the page


    // write the document content
    fileHandler = new FileHandler(this, getString(R.string.app_name));
    File pdf = fileHandler.getNewFileToWrite(AppConstants.FileExtensions.PDF); //crete and get file

    try {
        document.writeTo(new FileOutputStream(pdf));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error(e);
    }

    // close the document
    document.close();

}
```

Comment: Just put page width and height as per you requirement or get it from height and width of bitmap itself

Answer (score 1):

Now you can create a Bitmap for all childviews in the ListView.
After that, please process Bitmap as you like.

```
public List<Bitmap> getWholeListViewItemsToBitmap(ListView lv, Adapter adapter) {

    List<Bitmap> listBitmap    = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
    int itemsCount = adapter.getCount();
    int lvViewLines = lv.getChildCount();

    for(int from = 0; from < itemsCount;  from+= lvViewLines) {
        int to = from + lvViewLines;
        for(int i = from; i < to && i < itemsCount; i++) {
            View childView      = adapter.getView(i, null, lv);
            childView.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(lv.getWidth(), View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
                    View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
            childView.layout(0, 0, childView.getMeasuredWidth(), childView.getMeasuredHeight());
            childView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            childView.buildDrawingCache();
            listBitmap.add(childView.getDrawingCache());
        }
        lv.setScrollY(lvViewLines);
    }
    return listBitmap;
}
```