# How to generate PDF file for the whole listview android

Tags: android, pdf, bitmap

I have created the bitmap and have created the pdf file for the bitmap.
but I need to generate pdf for the whole listview which is scrollable.
Given below is is my code, please give me any suggestion, thanks in advance!!
I could not find the pdf creating application which could copy the entire UI or say in my case the entire listview into the pdf. If anybody could suggest what could be done in this case I would be grateful.

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button btn;
private LinearLayout llScroll;
private Bitmap bitmap;
private ListView listView;
ArrayList<String> myList;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btn = findViewById(R.id.btn);
    llScroll = findViewById(R.id.llScroll);
    listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
    String[] names= new String[]{"One","Two","Three","Four","Five","Six","Seven","One","Two","Three","Four","Five","Six","Seven"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,android.R.id.text1,names);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("size"," "+llScroll.getWidth() +"  "+llScroll.getWidth());
            bitmap = loadBitmapFromView(llScroll, llScroll.getWidth(), llScroll.getHeight());
            createPdf();
        }
    });

}
public static Bitmap loadBitmapFromView(View v, int width, int height) {
    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
    v.draw(c);
    return b; 
}
private void createPdf(){
    DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
    float hight = displaymetrics.heightPixels ;
    float width = displaymetrics.widthPixels ;
    int convertHighet = (int) hight, convertWidth = (int) width;
    PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();
    PdfDocument.PageInfo pageInfo = new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(convertWidth, convertHighet, 1).create();
    PdfDocument.Page page = document.startPage(pageInfo);

    Canvas canvas = page.getCanvas();

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    canvas.drawPaint(paint);

    bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, convertWidth, convertHighet, true);
    paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0 , null);
    document.finishPage(page);
    // write the document content
    String targetPdf = "/sdcard/pdffromScroll.pdf";
    File filePath;
    filePath = new File(targetPdf);
    try {
        document.writeTo(new FileOutputStream(filePath));

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Something wrong: " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    // close the document
    document.close();
    Toast.makeText(this, "PDF of Scroll is created!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    openGeneratedPDF();

}
private void openGeneratedPDF(){
    File file = new File("/sdcard/pdffromScroll.pdf");
    if (file.exists())
    {
        Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        try
        {
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        catch(ActivityNotFoundException e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No Application available to view pdf", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}}
```

Comment: check this  [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48924544/listview-to-pdf-in-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48924544/listview-to-pdf-in-android)

Comment: @HarshadPrajapati thanks for your reply, it's not working bro, would you suggest something other type